# How can I code if statement in a TensorFlow graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the model I want to build, there are two placeholders

```py
x = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[1000, 10])
tags = tf.placeholder('int32', shape=[1000, 1])
```

(1000 is just the number of examples)

`x` holds the inputs to neural networks, `tags` determines which one of the three neural networks will be used to compute the output.

```py
w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', [10, 1], tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
w2 = tf.get_variable('w2', [10, 1], tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
w3 = tf.get_variable('w3', [10, 1], tf.truncated_normal_initializer())

def nn_1(): return tf.matmul(x, w1)
def nn_2(): return tf.matmul(x, w2)
def nn_3(): return tf.matmul(x, w3)
```

I want to find an elegant way to implement a TensorFlow graph which can compute the output of an `x` given its `tag`.

```
[x1, x2, x3, ..., xn]
[1,  2,  3,  ..., 1]
[nn_1(x), nn_2(x), nn_3(x), ..., nn_1(x)]
```

If `x` and `tags` are not arrays, I can implement it with `tf.case`, for example,

```py
a = tf.placeholder('int32')
b = tf.placeholder('int32')
result = tf.case(
    {
        tf.equal(b, 1): a + 1, 
        tf.equal(b, 2): a + 2
    })
```

But I have no idea how to do when `x` and `tags` are arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some math trick to do the job.

let's say you want to implement the code you implemented but with a and b being arrays.

First, you compute an array of condition.
This would be the condition that must be true in order to apply the operation.
Typically conditions use "less", "equal", "greater" operation or a logical composition of those.
You can use `tf.bitwise` or `tf.math.logical*` for logical operation and `tf.math` for the others.
The condition must be a boolean array. 1 if the condition is true, 0 if false.

After that, you initialize the result array with the default value (what is in the "else" statement)

To apply the condition you simply multiply the condition array with the value you want to assign.

The code would be something like this.

```
//default value
result = tf.zeros(tf.shape(a)[0])
condition = tf.equal(b, index)
condition = tf.cast(condition, tf.float32)
result = tf.multiply(condition, a) + index
```

If you want to use `tag` as `index` of the functions array you need to use a 2d array. Create a 2d array of all possible combination nn X x.
This array will contain nn_j(x[i]) for each i,j couple.

To do this you need to create an array x X nn X 2 array.
First, expand x and create an array with x X nn array

if your x is x=[0,2,1] and len(n) = 2 then you need to have x_nn = [[0,0], [2,2], [1,1]].

```
nn_x = x
nn_x = tf.expand_dims(nn_x,0)
nn_x = tf.tile(nn_x, [len(nn), 1])
```

Then you create a 2d array with the same shape having the index of nn.
For the arrey used early index2d = [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]

```
index = tf.linspace(0,len(nn)-1)
index2d = tf.expand_dims(index,0)
index2d = tf.tile(index2d, tf.shape(x)[0])
```

Then you need to stack these and arrays, move the first dimension at the last place, then flat along axis 0 and 1.

In this way you will have map2d = [[0,0],[0,1],[2,0],[2,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
For each couple the first is the value of x, second is the index of the nn

Then you map this 2d array using the `tf.map_fn` function. write something like

```
tf.map_fn(t => [nn[t[1]](t[0]), t[1]], map2d)
```

Now you have all possible value of nn for each x

At this point, you can reshape back map2d compare map2d[:,:,1] with you tag and select the one that is equal.

```
#reshape map2d
# ...
# transform tag
tag2d = tag
tag2d = tf.expand_dims(tag2d,0)
tag2d = tf.tile(tag2d, [len(nn), 1])
result = tf.equal(tag, map2d[:,:,1])
```

the result will have only one non-zero value for each column

result = tf.multiply(result, map2d[:,:,0])
   result = tf.reduce_max(result, [1])

I didn't try the code, but the mechanism should work.

Hope this help